# about ssh multiple remote access

Tags: ssh, remote

```
ssh user@hostname /bin/bash << EOF
lshw
cat /etc/resolv.conf
EOF
```

I try this simple command and get details for one machine.How can i implement this to get details from multiple machine ?

Comment: `for machine in hostname1 hostname2 ... hostnameN; do ssh user@$machine <<< 'lshw; cat /etc/resolv.conf'; done`

Comment: @AlexP can we get this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use a `for` loop to iterate over a number of host names:

```
for machine in hostname1 hostname2 ... hostnameN; do
  ssh user@$machine <<< 'lshw; cat /etc/resolv.conf'
done
```

(`<<<` *string* is Bash here-string syntax, which can be used instead of a short here-document.)

Comment: @pa4080: No, not at all; it wouldn't even work. `ssh -n` prevents `ssh` from reading standard input. I *want* it to read standard input, I just redirect standard input from a string.

Comment: Why read the commands from stdin instead of just running them as `ssh host command`?

Comment: @fkraiem: Because that's how the OP did it. The question is about how to iterate over multiple hosts. Changing the way commands are passed would have introduced two modifications at the same time, which is a Bad Thing To Do.

Comment: hi AlexP thank you for the answer and i got the details but every time i put password how can i solve that problem becaz all machines are have same password

Comment: can you tell me how can i find the idle machine rather than frequently using machine

Comment: @TharmalingamMayuran: Use public key authentication.

Comment: @TharmalingamMayuran: The question does not mention anything about an idle machine.

Comment: yeah it's not mentioned anything about the idle machine! i ask help from you ? can you AlexP ?

Comment: @TharmalingamMayuran: You should formulate a question and post it. Then the community will have a chance to help.

Comment: @AlexP : sorry for that i'm new here that's why i put like that